# Is it possible for `renv` to be "bypassed" or temporarily turned off?

Tags: r, renv

I have an RStudio project that manages packages using `renv`, which works great.

But sometimes I want to debug or explore something using libraries on my main environment(right word?) that I don't want to add to the project. For example, maybe I want to run some long debug function and call `beepr::beep()` at the end. Is that possible without installing the `beepr` package to the project?

```
long_process()
beepr::beep() # How do I make this call?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could technically disable sandboxing, which is where `renv` prevents packages installed in the system library from being made available in the project (which is why you wouldn't be able to use `beepr::beep()` in your example. You can change your user configuration easily, just see the [documentation from env](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/reference/config.html). The setting here would be `renv.config.sandbox.enabled`.

However, I don't think that's the best option. Depending on the snapshot type settings described in `?renv::snapshot`, you needn't worry about installing `beepr` but it getting added to the lock file.

You can check or set the snapshot type using:

```r
renv::settings$snapshot.type()
```

If you install the `beepr` package in the environment, then depending on the type you will get:

- `"all"`: the only problematic setting. If you run snapshot with `beepr` actively loaded, it will be added to the lock file, which isn't what you want.
- `"implicit"`: as long as `beepr` isn't referenced in R code saved to the library, it won't be added to the lock file.
- `"explicit"`: only adds packages that are defined in `DESCRIPTION`.
- `"custom"`: as implied, is custom, but depends on files saved in the project, so would only add `beepr` if saved somewhere rather than just used interactively using debug.

So, in summary, unless you are using `"all"`, you should be safe to install and use `beepr`! If you are using `"all"`, then just be sure to `detach("package:beepr", unload = TRUE)` before running `snapshot()`.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the main title rather than the specific example used: to temporarily disable renv, use `renv::deactivate()`. This will mainly comment/deactivate the line  `source("renv/activate.R")` in `.Rprofile`, which has the main effect of changing your library path.

Check:

```r
proj <- "your-project-path"
## with renv
renv::activate(proj)
.libPaths()
#> [1] "your-project-path/renv/library/R-4.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
#> [2] "/usr/lib/R/library"
## without renv
renv::deactivate(proj)
.libPaths()
#> [1] "/home/usert/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2"
#> [2] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"                  
#> [3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                        
#> [4] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>